# How to convert following date: 2016-11-4 18:31:27 to NOV 04 in php and mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I have following dates: **2016-11-4 18:31:27 , 2016-11-1 18:31:27,2016-11-6 18:31:27, 2016-11-7 18:31:27**   and i  would like to convert it into  **NOV 04, NOV 01, NOV 06** when i execute the below code i am getting **jan 01, jan 01, jan 01, jan 01**

```
<?php
        $sqluseractivity = "SELECT user_register_date FROM `mlm_users` WHERE (`user_register_date` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 DAY))";
        $resultuser = $con->query($sqluseractivity);

        while($rowusers = $resultuser->fetch_assoc())
{

        $datetimeFromMysql = $rowusers['user_register_date'].'</br>';

        $dbtime = $datetimeFromMysql;

        $time = strtotime($dbtime);

        $myFormatForView = date("M d", $time);   

        echo $myFormatForView.'</br>' ;


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to handle this on the MySQL side using [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(user_register_date, '%b %d')
FROM mlm_users
WHERE user_register_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks "Tim Biegeleisen"  but  getting error on this query ** Undefined index: user_register_date **

Comment: I believe this query should run without error based on the information you gave us.